# Rails Passing local variable to escape_javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to pass my local variable to `escape_javascript` like this:

```
function renderPartial(partial) {
          $('body').append('<%=escape_javascript render(:partial => partial) %>');
}
```

But I got an error: undefined local variable or method `partial' for #<#:0x00007f9be09a36b0>

So my question is how I can pass my local variable in the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `<% %>` brackets is executed by ERB preprocessor on server side. It's Ruby code. As I see your variable `partial` is an argument of JS function, it will work on client side. So these 2 variables are from different realms. And local Ruby variable `partial` is not defined.

Please explain what you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: I see. I want to render partial depend on action of user. And I don’t want to add many of if else.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to do it, with ```if else``` or ```switch```. If you want to render your partial by calling JS method, you'll need to pre-render them on server side and pass to a client as raw HTML code. The other option (better) is instead of rendering make an AJAX call to the server which will return rendered partial.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just change `partial` variable name, I think `partial` is reserve keyword in rails.